# If $f(v)=0$ for all $f\in U^0$ then $v\in U$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, dual-spaces

How do I show that if $f(v)=0$ for all $f\in U^0$ then $v\in U$?

I know there are other answers on this but they fall short or I don’t understand them, in particular because most don’t prove linearity of the functional they create.

I tried extending a basis for $U$ but to no avail. I’m stuck!

Comment: For context, $U^0$ is the annihilator of the subspace $U$

Comment: What is $U$ ? It needs additional context, we can't help you in these conditions.

Comment: @Tuvasbien subspace of finite-dim $V$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $K$ and $U$ a subspace of $V$.

> Claim: If $v\in V$ is such that $f(v)=0$ for all $f\in U^0$ then $v\in U$.

Let $\{u_1,\ldots,u_r\}$ be a basis of $U$ if $v\notin U$ then $\{v,u_1,\ldots,u_r\}$ is a linearly independent set and thus we can extend it to a basis of $V$, let this new basis be $\{v,u_1,\ldots,u_r,w_1,\ldots,w_m\}$ now we define $T\colon V\to K$ as follows
\begin{align*}
T\left(av+\sum_{i=1}^ra_iu_i+\sum_{i=1}^mb_iw_i\right)=a+\sum_{i=1}^mb_i
\end{align*}

$T$ is well defined because $\{v,u_1,\ldots,u_r,w_1,\ldots,w_m\}$ is a basis of $V$, now we notice that $T$ is linear since
\begin{align*}
&T\left(\lambda(av+\sum_{i=1}^ra_iu_i+\sum_{i=1}^mb_iw_i)+(bv+\sum_{i=1}^r\alpha_iu_i+\sum_{i=1}^m\beta_iw_i)\right) \\
=&T\left((\lambda a+b)v+\sum_{i=1}^r(\lambda a_i+\alpha_i)u_i+\sum_{i=1}^m(\lambda b_i+\beta_i)w_i\right) \\
=& \lambda a+b+\sum_{i=1}^m(\lambda b_i+\beta_i) \\
=&\left(\lambda(a+\sum_{i=1}^mb_i)\right)+\left(b+\sum_{i=1}^m\beta_i\right) \\
=& \lambda T\left(av+\sum_{i=1}^ra_iu_i+\sum_{i=0}^mb_iw_i\right)+T\left(bv+\sum_{i=1}^r\alpha_iu_i+\sum_{i=0}^m\beta_iw_i\right).
\end{align*}

We also notice that $T\in U^0$ since given $u=\sum_{i=1}^ra_iu_i\in U$ we have
$$
T(u)=T\left(0v+\sum_{i=1}^ra_iu_i+\sum_{i=1}^m0w_i=0\right)=0+\sum_{i=1}^m0=0.
$$
Finally, it's clear that $T(v)=1$ and thus there's $f\in U^0$ such that $f(v)\not=0$.